# A problem that is computable yet doesn't lie in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I'm trying to find a problem that is computable but not in **NP**.

I checked and I havent found any duplicates(I hope so too). We were asked if there is a problem that exists that is computable yet doesnt lie in **NP** and we should name the problem and explain why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

The [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) says that, if you allow more time, you can solve more problems. It's normally stated for deterministic machines but it applies to nondeterministic ones, too. In particular, nondeterministic Turing machines running in exponential time can solve problems that no polynomial-time NTM can. NTMs running in doubly-exponential time can solve even more, and so on for triply-exponential, quadruply-exponential and so on.

So you need to investigate the class [**NEXP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXPTIME), and find some problems in there that are known not to be in **NP**.